# Proving expectations for different functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Currently studying probability from Sheldon Ross' A first course in probability. Came across the following question:

Let N be a nonnegative integer-valued random variable. For non-negative values $a_{j}, j 
\ge 1$, show that:

$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(a_{1} + ..... + a_{j})P(N=j)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}P(N\ge i)$

I was able to do this just by expanding the LHS. But I have been beating my head up over the following subparts.

a. E[N] = $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(N \ge 1)$

If I set all the $a_{i}$ = 1, but the issue is how do I show the LHS to be equal to E[N].

b. E[N(N+1)] = $2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}iP(N \ge i)$.

I do not even know how to get started here even though I know that we can make use of the fact that the given random variable has some form of arithmetic summation formula .

But full answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you set $a_j=1$ for every $j\in \mathbb{N}$ then $$a_1+ \dots + a_j=j$$ making the LHS $E(N)$. Now if you set $a_j=j$ for every $j\in \mathbb{N}$ then $$a_1+\dots + a_j=\frac{j(j+1)}{2} $$ which makes the LHS $E\Big(\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\Big)$

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer for the third part?

Comment: In the third part I am using the formula $$E\big(g(N)\big)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}g(j)P(N=j)$$ by taking $g(x)=\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$

Comment: I am also using the fact that $$\frac{1+\dots+j}{n}=\frac{j(j+1)}{2}$$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: I am sorry but could you post the step-by-step solution in your answer, It is very confusing to me how the 2 in the denominator vanished

Comment: The 2 didn't vanish, it was just brought to the other side of the equation.